# Python Dash: Fitting a table and a graph in one row of a grid

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am trying to fit a table and a graph in one single row of a grid. I have tried to resize both of them to fit by setting the `style`, but for some odd reason the table is placed beneath the graph.

Here is the code. What is it caused by?

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, no_update, dash_table
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])


data = OrderedDict(
    [
        ("Date", ["2015-01-01", "2015-10-24", "2016-05-10", "2017-01-10", "2018-05-10", "2018-08-15"]),
        ("Region", ["Montreal", "Toronto", "New York City", "Miami", "San Francisco", "London"]),
        ("Temperature", [1, -20, 3.512, 4, 10423, -441.2]),
        ("Humidity", [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]),
        ("Pressure", [2, 10924, 3912, -10, 3591.2, 15]),
    ]
)
df_a = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([(name, col_data * 10) for (name, col_data) in data.items()]))
df_a = df_a.iloc[0:20].copy()


df_b = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

dropdown_country_a = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="dropdown-a",
    options=df_b.country,
    value="Turkey",
)

dropdown_country_b = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="dropdown-b",
    options=df_b.country,
    value="Canada"
)

f1 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))
f2 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))
f3 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))

aa = {'width': '40%', 'display': 'inline-block'}

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("USD", style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="1", figure=f1, style=aa), dcc.Graph(id="2", figure=f2, style=aa)]),
        html.Div([
        
        html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(id="table", data=df_a.to_dict('records'), columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_a.columns])], style=aa),
        
        html.Div([dbc.Container([
            dbc.Row(dbc.Col([dropdown_country_a, dropdown_country_b], lg=6, sm=12)),
            dbc.Row(dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="asd"), lg=6, sm=12))])], style=aa)
    ])
    ])
])



# Callback for line_geo graph
@app.callback(
    Output("asd", "figure"),
    Input("dropdown-a", "value"),
    Input("dropdown-b", "value"),
)
def make_line_geo_graph(country_a, country_b):
    dff = df_b[df_b.country.isin([country_a, country_b])]

    fig = px.line_geo(
        dff,
        locations="iso_alpha",
        projection="orthographic",
    )

    fig_locations = px.line_geo(
        dff, locations="iso_alpha", projection="orthographic", fitbounds="locations"
    )

    fig.update_traces(
        line_width=3,
        line_color="red",
    )

    fig_locations.update_traces(
        line_width=3,
        line_color="red",
    )

    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better control of the components of your Dash app, you should consider using `dbc.Col` components within `dbc.Row()` components. If you exchange your:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("USD", style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="1", figure=f1, style=aa),
                 dcc.Graph(id="2", figure=f2, style=aa)]),
        html.Div([

            html.Div([
                dash_table.DataTable(id="table", data=df_a.to_dict('records'), columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_a.columns])], style=aa),

            html.Div([dbc.Container([
                dbc.Row(
                    dbc.Col([dropdown_country_a, dropdown_country_b], lg=6, sm=12)),
                dbc.Row(dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="asd"), lg=6, sm=12))])], style=aa)
        ])
    ])
])
```

With:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("USD", style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="1", figure=f1, style=aa),
                 dcc.Graph(id="2", figure=f2, style=aa)]),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([dropdown_country_a, dropdown_country_b], lg=6, sm=12)]),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([dash_table.DataTable(id="table", data=df_a.to_dict(
            'records'), columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_a.columns])]), dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(id="asd")])])

    ])
])
```

Then you'll get the following setup:

[image]

From here you can tweak the layout of your app with the `width` attribute of your `dbc.Col` components.

#### Complete code:

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, no_update, dash_table
import plotly.express as px
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])


data = OrderedDict(
    [
        ("Date", ["2015-01-01", "2015-10-24", "2016-05-10",
         "2017-01-10", "2018-05-10", "2018-08-15"]),
        ("Region", ["Montreal", "Toronto", "New York City",
         "Miami", "San Francisco", "London"]),
        ("Temperature", [1, -20, 3.512, 4, 10423, -441.2]),
        ("Humidity", [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]),
        ("Pressure", [2, 10924, 3912, -10, 3591.2, 15]),
    ]
)
df_a = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([(name, col_data * 10)
                    for (name, col_data) in data.items()]))
df_a = df_a.iloc[0:20].copy()


df_b = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

dropdown_country_a = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="dropdown-a",
    options=df_b.country,
    value="Turkey",
)

dropdown_country_b = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="dropdown-b",
    options=df_b.country,
    value="Canada"
)

f1 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))
f2 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))
f3 = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color="Gold"))

aa = {'width': '40%', 'display': 'inline-block'}

# app.layout = html.Div([
#     html.H1("USD", style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
#     html.Div(children=[
#         html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="1", figure=f1, style=aa),
#                  dcc.Graph(id="2", figure=f2, style=aa)]),
#         html.Div([

#             html.Div([
#                 dash_table.DataTable(id="table", data=df_a.to_dict('records'), columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_a.columns])], style=aa),

#             html.Div([dbc.Container([
#                 dbc.Row(
#                     dbc.Col([dropdown_country_a, dropdown_country_b], lg=6, sm=12)),
#                 dbc.Row(dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="asd"), lg=6, sm=12))])], style=aa)
#         ])
#     ])
# ])

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("USD", style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="1", figure=f1, style=aa),
                 dcc.Graph(id="2", figure=f2, style=aa)]),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([dropdown_country_a, dropdown_country_b], lg=6, sm=12)]),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([dash_table.DataTable(id="table", data=df_a.to_dict(
            'records'), columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df_a.columns])]), dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(id="asd")])])

    ])
])


# Callback for line_geo graph
@app.callback(
    Output("asd", "figure"),
    Input("dropdown-a", "value"),
    Input("dropdown-b", "value"),
)
def make_line_geo_graph(country_a, country_b):
    dff = df_b[df_b.country.isin([country_a, country_b])]

    fig = px.line_geo(
        dff,
        locations="iso_alpha",
        projection="orthographic",
    )

    fig_locations = px.line_geo(
        dff, locations="iso_alpha", projection="orthographic", fitbounds="locations"
    )

    fig.update_traces(
        line_width=3,
        line_color="red",
    )

    fig_locations.update_traces(
        line_width=3,
        line_color="red",
    )

    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great. The dropdown for the right graph are above the table, which is in the left pane though. I assume it is because the row with the dropdowns only has one column (?) Is it possible to right-align it?

Comment: I used `html.Br()`, that seemed to do the trick!